# How do I check if a file is a symbolic link to a directory?

Tags: bash, shell, test

I can check, if a file exists and is a symbolic link with -L

```
for file in *; do
    if [[ -L "$file" ]]; then echo "$file is a symlink"; else echo "$file is not a symlink"; fi
done
```

and if it is a directory with -d:

```
for file in *; do
    if [[ -d "$file" ]]; then echo "$file is a directory"; else echo "$file is a regular file"; fi
done
```

But how can I test for only links to directories?

---

I simulated all cases in a test folder:

```
/tmp/test# ls
a  b  c/  d@  e@  f@

/tmp/test# file *
a: ASCII text
b: ASCII text
c: directory
d: symbolic link to `c'
e: symbolic link to `a'
f: broken symbolic link to `nofile'
```

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Just combine the two tests with `&&`:

```bsh
if [[ -L "$file" && -d "$file" ]]
then
    echo "$file is a symlink to a directory"
fi
```

Or, for POSIX compliant-syntax, use:

```bsh
if [ -L "$file" ] && [ -d "$file" ]
...
```

*Note: the first syntax using `[[ expr1 && expr2 ]]` is valid, but only works in certain shells such as ksh (where it comes from), bash or zsh. The second syntax using `[ expr1 ] && [ expr2 ]` is POSIX-compliant and even Bourne-compatible, meaning it will work in all modern `sh` and `sh`-like shells*

Comment: If you want to check hidden files and directories too preceed this before: `shopt -s dotglob`

Answer (score 15):

Here is a single command which will recursively list symlinks whose target is a directory (starting in the current directory):

`find . -type l -xtype d`

Reference: http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/6105/find-all-symlinks-that-link-to-directories

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `find` and using a function:

```
dosomething () {
    echo "doing something with $1"; 
}
find -L -path './*' -prune -type d| while read file; do 
    if [[ -L "$file" && -d "$file" ]];
        then dosomething "$file";
    fi; 
done
```

Comment: Using `find` and a `while read` for that is kinda overkill...

Comment: Find is really useful if you search only for certain files