# How to verify the target of a symbolic link points toward a particular path

Tags: bash, shell, symlink

Within a bash script, I know I can check if a file is a symbolic link with the following syntax

```
if [ -L $path ]
```

Does any one know how I would test if that path was linked to a particular path? E.g. I want to check whether the target of `$path` is `/some/where`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check if a file is a symbolic link to a directory?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96907/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-is-a-symbolic-link-to-a-directory)

Comment: Do you mean linked to _by_ a particular path? Couldn't you do a `readlink` on the known path and compare it against the path you're testing?

Comment: @Bratchley. Yes, that's what I meant.. thanks for the answer.

Comment: I strongly urge you to always put shell variables in quotes (e.g., `if [ -L "$path" ]` ) unless you have a good reason not to and you're sure you know what you're doing.

Comment: @G-Man thanks for the great feedback.. subconsciously I know to do that, but forget it in practice.. the reinforcement helps.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you want to check whether `$path` is a symbolic link whose target is `/some/where`, you can use the `readlink` utility. It isn't POSIX, but it's available on many systems (GNU/Linux, BusyBox, *BSD, …).

```
if [ "$(readlink -- "$path")" = /some/where ]; then …
```

Note that this is an exact text comparison. If the target of the link is `/some//where`, or if it's `where` and the value of `$path` is `/some/link`, then the texts won't match.

Many versions of `readlink` support the option `-f`, which canonicalizes the path by expanding all symbolic links.

Many shells, including dash, ksh, bash and zsh, support the `-ef` operator in the `test` builtin to test whether two files are the same (hard links to the same file, after following symbolic links). This feature is also widely supported but not POSIX.

```
if [ "$path" -ef "/some/where" ]; then …
```

Comment: the first example does not work when the link points to a relative path...

Comment: @inemanja Sure it does. But as I state, this is a _text_ comparison. It treats different paths to the same target as different. If you want to test whether the target of a symbolic link is a particular **file**, rather than a particular **path**, use one of the methods I describe below.

Comment: It's not safe to treat file location as strings for that exact reason - the first example compares strings hence it shows that "/dir/file.txt" and "/dir/../dir/../dir/file.txt" are different files, and they are not. The second example is much more precise.

Comment: How about wrapping the path in `$(realpath "../dir/../otherdir/file.ext")` ?

Comment: @MogensTrasherDK How about that? I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: If `relative` path is a problem, translate to `absolute` path. Is that more clear?

Comment: BTW. I agree that the `if [ "$path" -ef "/some/where" ]; then` is probably a better option inmost cases.