# Why says readlink that there is no such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, readlink

I am creating a bash function that should return true/false if a specified symlink refers to specified target. I based myself on https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192341/40237

However, I am having trouble getting `readlink` to work as I want:

```
is_symlink_to () {
# $1 = symlink / $2 = symlink target
    echo "arg1: $1 and arg2: $2"
    echo readlink arg 1 is: $(readlink -v $1 )   # -v for troubleshooting
    if  [ "$(readlink -- $1)" = $2 ]; then
        echo "$1 is a symlink to $2"
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
   fi
}

...

if is_symlink_to "~/$file" "$dir/$file" ; then
    echo "is already symlinked"
else
   ...
fi
```

**Question**: Why does `readlink -v` return `No such file or directory`?

```
arg1: ~/.bash_profile and arg2: /home/me/dotfiles/.bash_profile
readlink: '~/.bash_profile': No such file or directory
readlink arg 1 is:
```

If I run `readlink` from a bash shell, it works fine:

```
me@mango:~/dotfiles$ readlink -v ~/.bash_profile
/home/me/dotfiles/.bash_profile
```

Comment: @ilkkachu: I've updated my post to include the function call

Comment: The answer of @UmairKhan looks right. Please try what happens if you remove the double quotes around the first variable of your call to `is_symlink_to`, and try if instead `is_symlink_to ~/"$file" "$dir/$file"` works.

Comment: @AdminBee: Works perfect now. Thanks! I hadn't expected the tilde to be the problem. If you put it in an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: See also `[ "$file1" -ef "$file2" ]` to check whether two paths refer to the same file (after symlink resolution)

Comment: Remember to quote your parameter expansions! (but not `~`) and use `--` to mark the end of options for `readlink` (`readlink -v -- "$file"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @UmairKhan, the tilde expansion doesn't work inside double-quotes, so the statement

```
if is_symlink_to "~/$file" "$dir/$file" ; then
```

would look for a file (in your example) `.bash_profile` inside a directory *literally* named `~` inside your current directory, instead of inside your home directory.

It should work if you only enclose the actual "bash variable part" in parentheses, as in

```
if is_symlink_to ~/"$file" "$dir/$file"; then
```

Although completely omitting the double parentheses around your first argument would also work (`is_symlink_to ~/$file "$dir/$file"`) , this is not advisable as it might stumble upon filenames with special characters.

Answer (score 1):

The `~` in `"~/$file"` is being treated literally, due to the surrounding quotes.

In script form, this is better represented as:

`"${HOME}/$file"`

The `${HOME}` variable is equivalent to `~` and will expand within double quotes.

Comment: Thanks.  I've accepted AdminBee's answer, but using the $HOME variable is indeed how I finally handled it.